# first order differential equation - mixing problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

[image]

I don't understand here how they got the concentration out. Can someone explain please? I understand what the incoming concentration is but am confused about the outgoing concentration rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well mixed air at concentration ${C \over 100}$ leaves the room at 5 $m^3/s$. Hence the loss is $5{C \over 100} = {C \over 20}$.

Comment: Parsing these questions can be tough at times.